# Blocking access to certain URLs on nginx using iptables

Tags: nginx, security, iptables

We are using nginx and need to block access to certain URLs or URLs parts that don't exist on the server and are being used by hackers to probe the server.

To effectely block the URLs we decided to put them on the firewall. These are some of the blocks:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/myaccount" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/login" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string ".action" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string ".asp" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/admin" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/connectors/" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/default/" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/filemanager/" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/editor/" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/include/" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/convert/" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "wp-json" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/wp-admin" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/administrator" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/wp/" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/modules/" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/new/" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/old/" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/wordpress/wp-admin" --algo kmp -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m string --string "/test/" --algo kmp -j DROP
```

The downside is after putting these rules nginx became inaccessible. It was either giving a 402 or 403 error.

Any idea?

**Edit**

The problem could be with the rules themselves than where they are put. Have tried putting them under nginx and it stops responding:

```
  location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login|old/|new/|modules/|wp/|administrator|wordpress/wp-admin|test/|wp-json|convert/|include/|editor/|filemanager/|default/|connectors/|admin|login|myaccount) {
       deny all;
  }
```

Comment: If you'd like to effectively block over SSL too at some point, I'd suggest backing up to the beginning where you decided to use iptables instead of the nginx config and change your mind.

Comment: Why do you need to block those URLs? Are they causing problems? Are you seeing performance issues?

Comment: @Tim there are both performance and security issues. First these URLs are called in a flood causing resource waste returning 403 errors. 2nd, these URLs don't exist on the server. They are being used to probe what's on the server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to block URLs in nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/383256/whats-the-best-way-to-block-urls-in-nginx)

Comment: As yoonix says, you should block in Nginx, as that will work for http and https. https is (likely) decoded after iptables, so it can't block those. You might also consider fail2ban.

Comment: @yoonix is correct.  Back off those rules.  iptables is like taking a sledgehammer to swat a fly, or a firehose to put out a candle.  This is like when I was married and driving, I sometimes would tell my wife to just shut her eyes if she didn't like what she was seeing.  My point is, ask yourself what harm are they causing?  That is where your focus should be.  To make sure certain pages are only accessible from your internal LAN, simply dropping all access to them is going to cause you more harm than having outsiders take a little of your bandwidth.  You want to "right-size" your approach.

Comment: @SDsolar when under attack I become paranoid given that I am  not a security expert and try to juggle between programming and system administration at the same time. We also have tens of sites we're trying to protect. Having it in iptables protects all those sites at once, and don't have to remember which rules have been out where. The only reason for falling back to nginx is if the rules won't work under HTTPS as suggested by someone but I am not sure about this and we'll have to investigate.

Comment: The rules won't work in `iptables`. TLS is terminated in nginx / OpenSSL that nginx uses. You can put all the rules in a single nginx configuration file and use nginx `include` to include those in every site configuration.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen okay we'll consider that if and when we use HTTPS though it's unlikely people doing a probe will do it over HTTPS. But still that doesn't answer the question  why nginx stopped responding?

Comment: I know that "under attack" feeling.  I used to host over 100 websites at my home about 15 years ago.  That part was fine.  The trouble started when I began offering email.  I should never have done that.  The constant barrage of probes was overwhelming.  I would spend an hour each day blocking specific IPs but it never slowed it down.  I will never, ever, run an email server again.  The web server kept on humming even when the email server would bog down with it all.  I was glad to sell the company and make it someone else's problem.

Comment: You need to run TCPDump on both ends of the connection and post the output in the question so that we can analyze why this happens. Actually your `iptables` shouldn't even work, as the `-I` expects the number where to place the rule after the chain specified. It might also be that some of your blocks match some crucial HTTP protocol text that makes it stop responding. We cannot know unless you list all the blocking rules you had.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen problem could be with rules themselves than with IPTABLES. Tried putting them under nginx and it completely freezes then throws 502 error.

Comment: Filtering URLs is a level 7 problem. Using iptables is for level 2/3/4 of the TCP/IP (or OSI) stack, so clearly not the best soltuion.